# flask_sqlalchemy module cant be found error

Tags: python-3.x, web, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I want to use the flask_sqlalchemy module in my web app. But when I run "flask run" it gives me the following error:

```
        from flask_sqlalchemy import 
        SQLAlchemy
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module 
        named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

I am running this in a virtual env with python3.7 and pip3. It says that all packages have been installed. Ive tried a whole bunch of things with no luck.

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment

Comment: Yeah I did. I did "source venv/bin/activate". It seems to be happening with my flask_login too. Not sure if its an issue with the environment or flask.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a whole bunch of stuff. Setting the environment variable FLASK_ENV=development and then to production somehow fixed.